# How to declare two dimensional arrays using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

Hello there I am having trouble declaring two dimensional arrays using pointers. I am new to C.

```
int main(){

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    int *xdim;
    int *ydim;


    printf("Enter x:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x); 
    printf("Enter y:\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    xdim = &x;
    ydim = &y;

    char sq[xdim][ydim];

    return 0;
}
```

I want the two dimentionial array char sq to hold the values inputed by the user. I get error non-integer type *int. I am also new to pointers.

Comment: Guys sorry for my answer. I'm getting crazy getting a dll work. Sorry @Anonymous Penguin my answer  was wrong ...

Comment: Just use `char sq[x][y];`, you do not need xdim/ydim

Comment: @Ctx he just wants to test how pointers work. Use `char sq[*xdim][*ydim]`

Comment: They are initialized `xdim = &x` if `scanf` doesn't return error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s (which are allowed in C99, or as an extension to many compilers), all you need to do is:

```
int xdim, ydim;
scanf("%d %d", &xdim, &ydim);

char vla_array[xdim][ydim];
```

As you can see, there is no need for pointers.

---

The 2nd option is to use "ordinary" arrays. You need to declare an array with big enough size, and use only a part of it:

```
#DEFINE X_MAX_DIM 100
#DEFINE Y_MAX_DIM 100

char vla_array[X_MAX_DIM][Y_MAX_DIM];

int xdim, ydim;
scanf("%d %d", &xdim, &ydim);
// check xdim and ydim are acceptable sizes

// from now on you use up to `xdim x ydim` of your array, even if
// it was declared as `100x100`
```

You can use this only when you know in advance the maximum allowed dimensions of your array.

---

The 3rd option is to use dynamic allocation. This is the only option if the array is very big. However this is an advanced topic, so you will not deal with this right now.

Comment: You don't need to mention VLA as though they're something unusual. They are a core part of C. OP is using C, therefore they can use VLA. If they can't use VLA, they should specify that they are using C89, or a compiler that has chosen to use the no-VLA option, *not* pure C. (*Not* providing VLA is a permitted extension. By default, they are assumed to be allowed.)

Comment: @Leushenko I think I was pretty clear as when are VLA accepted.

Comment: @Leushenko Using VLA's is still a choice, for example they should be avoided for huge arrays.

Comment: It's a linguistic issue: "if you are OK with..." implies there might be something non-standard about them, and there's certainly no need to mention extensions. New C users shouldn't be discouraged from using standard features.

Comment: @Leushenko ok, I see your point. I removed the "if you are OK" part, but I left the "C99 and extension" info.

Comment: OK, but why leave that part? They're **not** an extension (from C11 onwards, *failing* to support them is a permitted extension, but the compiler needs to announce that). They're a standard part of the core C language. You don't need to mention a version number - it makes it sound like it's something distinct from "pure C". This is still misleading for people learning the language.

Comment: @Leushenko If only there was a modern major widespread compiler who doesn't have VLAs, then the note would be justifiable. Oh wait, I remembered: Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio *doesn't support C*, so answers for C shouldn't take it into account. It only supports C89 with some enhancements as a legacy feature. Promoting the notions that a) C89 counts as C, or b) you should learn to "code down" to the standards of broken tools, is *actively harmful*.

Comment: @Leushenko I not once promoted to "code down". I just added an information. That is VLA and is supported as a standard since C99. It's an information that is correct. I didn't say or implied that VLA's should't be used. And ultimately we got caught up in something **minor**.

Answer (score 1):

```
int** ptr = NULL;
ptr = new int*[val];

for(int i=0; i < val; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = new int[val];
}
```

above code allocates 2d array of val*val

Answer (score 0):

change `char sq[xdim][ydim];` to `char sq[*xdim][*ydim];`, else you pass the location of the value rather than the value itself.
But it is unnecessary to use pointers in this case, you could just use `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you sowed the error occured because in this declaration

```
char sq[xdim][ydim];
```

there are used pointers  `xdim` and `ydim` instead of integers. You could write

```
char sq[*xdim][*ydim];
```

Though there is no need to use pointers such a way.

If your compiler supports Variable Length Arrays then you can for example just write

```
int main( void )
{
    size_t m = 0;
    size_t n = 0;

    printf("Enter x:\n");
    scanf("%zu", &m); 
    printf("Enter y:\n");
    scanf("%zu", &n);

    if ( !m || !n ) return 1;

    char sq[m][n];

    //...     

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise you have to allocate arrays dynamically. For example

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    size_t m = 0;
    size_t n = 0;

    printf("Enter x:\n");
    scanf("%zu", &m); 
    printf("Enter y:\n");
    scanf("%zu", &n);

    if ( !m || !n ) return 1;

    char **sq = malloc( m * sizeof( char * ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) sq[i] = malloc( n * sizeof( char ) );

    //...

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) free( sq[i] );
    free( sq );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if i understand what you're asking this should work.

Using a single pointer within a 2D array;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int x = 0, y = 0;
char *arr = (char *)malloc(x * y * sizeof(int));
```